# nvcc runs from command line but not from shell

Tags: linux, bash, cuda, nvcc

I tried to run this command form command line:

```
nvcc src/lib/Globals.cpp src/lib/Comp/* src/lib/Decomp/* src/main.cpp -lpthread  -o debug/TEST
```

it runs perfectly,generates errors or warnings when compiling and so on.but when executed from a shell it produces this error:

```
./debug/test.sh: line 137: nvcc: command not found
```

this is the relevant part of my .bashrc file although I don't see how that might be the problem.

```
export CUDA_HOME=/SomePATH/CUDA
export PATH=$PATH:$CUDA_HOME/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CUDA_HOME/lib:$CUDA_HOME/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

the same error happens with nvprof.

Comment: what is the output of 'which nvcc' from your command line?

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [su]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.bashrc` is only read for interactive shells. Move your commands to set up the environment for CUDA to `.profile` instead, which is also read for noninteractive shells (batch jobs/shell scripts).

You can read up about shell initialization files by running `info bash` and going to *Bash Features*, then *Bash Startup Files*